# How can I create post title cloud (instead of tag cloud) in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a cloud of titles of the existing posts. Just like a tag cloud as seen in the following image, but there must be post titles instead of tags. 
How can I do this?

http://news.techgenie.com/files/Tag-Cloud1.jpg

Comment: Were you able to get it to work with the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

With a little research I was able to find a plugin that does exactly what you are needing.

Here you go: [Title Cloud Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-title-cloud/)

Comment: I've seen it too, but unfortunately it's not been updated for 2 years.

Comment: Please try it out, it may work with the current version.